# CGDisplayCreateImageForRect: how to ignore a specific NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, appkit

I'm looking to make a sample "lens" app which show what's is visible under the current mouse location. I've used CGDisplayCreateImageForRect to get a portion of the screen under the mouse location.

Now I would to attach a transparent window at the same location of the mouse and show this lens directly under the mouse position; however under this location there is...my transparent window with the result zoom... ops!

Is there a way to exclude a particular window from the snapshot or another method to get the current image at mouse position by ignoring something behind it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with that function. You can use the CGWindowList API to do it: either `CGWindowListCreateImage()` or `CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray()`. These let you specify criteria to select the windows to include or an explicit list of windows.

It's not clearly documented how to obtain the window ID of one of your own windows. The supported way is probably to query information about all on-screen windows using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` and then use the properties to identify yours. That said, I believe that the `NSWindow` property `windowNumber` does in fact correspond the Core Graphics window ID.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. In order to take the CGWindowID of a window I need to simply get the windowNumber: ```CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[myNSWindow windowNumber];```. I'll answer to the question with a more complete code in just a moment.

Answer (score 3):

@ken-thomases point me to the right direction. The function I've used to include all windows and exclude my single one is `CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray()`.

The code below is a small example:

```
// Get onscreen windows
CGWindowID windowIDToExcude = (CGWindowID)[myNSWindow windowNumber];
CFArrayRef onScreenWindows = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
CFMutableArrayRef finalList = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, onScreenWindows);
for (long i = CFArrayGetCount(finalList) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    CGWindowID window = (CGWindowID)(uintptr_t)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(finalList, i);
    if (window == windowIDToExcude)
            CFArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(finalList, i);
}
// Get the composite image
CGImageRef ref = CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray(myRectToGrab, finalList, kCGWindowListOptionAll);
```

Comment: For swift googlers, see this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37050461/143447