# How we can Manipulate Screenshot with blank screen in ios app?

Tags: swift

```
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        // executes after screenshot
}
```

This code works after taking screenshot.
Is there any way we can replace view with blank view while taking screenshot?
As we know we cannot disable screenshot in ios.

Comment: Hope this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043708/how-to-ignore-my-apps-window-on-screenshot-swift-2-0

Comment: Can you give more detailed solution??

Comment: @Vicksheet did you found solution for this ?